# How do I upgrade mongodb 1.8 to 2.2 on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, mongodb

Following this guide: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/ I ended up with mongodb 18 on my Ubuntu 10.04.

I've just read the 2.2 mongodb release notes on upgrading and it says to just replace the binary. Would that be /usr/lib/mongodb/mongod ?

It looks like the 2.2 tar has several files I might need to copy over: mongo, mongod, mongoexport, mongodump, mongofiles, mongoimport, mongorestore, mongos, xulwrapper

Can I just copy and paste all of those over to replace the old versions of those files?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite the MongoDB binaries, that will work fine

However, there is no possible way you installed version 1.2.2 - that version is not available on the repositories mentioned in the installation instructions (and it is ancient - from Jan 2010) - the only versions are 1.8, 2.0 and 2.2.

You may be confusing it with a driver version - PHP maybe?

If you run `/usr/lib/mongodb/mongod --version` it will tell you the version of mongod that is actually installed.

If you installed one of the lower versions and want to upgrade, I would recommend just removing the older package:

```
sudo apt-get remove mongodb18-10gen
```

Then install the latest stable release (as of writing that would be 2.2.2):

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb-10gen
```

Comment: I was referring to the shell version by mistake. Will edit to fix it. Thank you.

Comment: edited to include a way to upgrade from the lower versions to the latest stable